# Splitting a text file twice in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, text

I've got the following text file.

```
bob jones,19,moore reef,yes,no
jenny smith, 21,reef park,yes,yes
any body, 12,somewhere,no,no
```

I would like each line to be in a separate array OR I would like separate arrays for each piece of data (eg. name_array, age_array, destination_array, etc).

How can I do either way?

Answer (score 5):

Load it with the CSV parser from the standard library:

```
require 'csv'
a = CSV.open('x.csv').map { |r| r.map(&:strip) }
```

The will give you an `a` like this:

```
[
    [ "bob jones",   "19", "moore reef", "yes", "no"  ],
    [ "jenny smith", "21", "reef park",  "yes", "yes" ],
    [ "any body",    "12", "somewhere",  "no",  "no"  ]
]
```

Then you can use [`b = a.transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000261) to flip the rows and columns to get this in `b`:

```
[
    [ "bob jones", "jenny smith", "any body" ],
    [ "19", "21", "12" ],
    [ "moore reef", "reef park", "somewhere" ],
    [ "yes", "yes", "no" ],
    [ "no", "yes", "no" ]
]
```

And then from there you can pull out the individual arrays if you want them:

```
names, ages, destinations, flags1, flags2 = *b
```

I had to guess the `flags1` and `flags2` names.

Answer (score 1):

Split the file into lines with `readlines` then for each line use `String#split` over the comma.  Then, if you like (for your "second way") transpose.

Given the file people.txt

```
bob jones,19,moore reef,yes,no
jenny smith, 21,reef park,yes,yes
any body, 12,somewhere,no,no
```

Then lines of the file are obatined like this:

```
people = IO.readlines("people.txt")
p people
```

This gives

```
["bob jones,19,moore reef,yes,no\n", 
 "jenny smith, 21,reef park,yes,yes\n", 
 "any body, 12,somewhere,no,no"]
```

At this point you have some extra newlines in there, but they go away when you process line by line, adding `String#chomp`:

```
result = []
people = IO.readlines("people.txt")
people.each {|line| result << line.chomp.split(",")}
p result
```

This gives

```
[["bob jones", "19", "moore reef", "yes", "no"], 
 ["jenny smith", " 21", "reef park", "yes", "yes"], 
 ["any body", " 12", "somewhere", "no", "no"]]
```

The second part of your question is how to get *slices* per column.  The easiest way here is to use `transpose`.  Like so:

```
result = []
people = IO.readlines("people.txt")
people.each {|line| result << line.chomp.split(",")}
p result.transpose
```

This gives

```
[["bob jones", "jenny smith", "any body"], 
 ["19", " 21", " 12"], 
 ["moore reef", "reef park", "somewhere"], 
 ["yes", "yes", "no"], 
 ["no", "yes", "no"]]
```

**UPDATE** I had to edit my answer to add in the chomps!  Also FYI you may want to add in some string trimming, too.  I'll let you look that one up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did it this was;

```
f1 = File.open(filename,"r")                
f1.each do | line|
  i += 1 
  data = line.split(',')
  #store data into arrays
  passenger_name[i] = data[0] #passenger's name
  passenger_age[i] = data[1]
  passenger_destination[i] = data[2]
  passenger_meal[i] = data[3]
  passenger_dive[i] = data[4]
  end
```

It stores each of the names, ages, destinations, etc in a different array which solves my problem better. Thanks for all your repsonses.